# How do I access member variables from a repeating timer callback

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi-pico

Using the RPI Pico SDK, I have three files.
I want to use a callback function and access private members of a class.
The callback function is in an SDK and I can not modify it.
How do I do this?

```
/////// test.h
bool main_loop_timer_callback(struct repeating_timer *t);
class MyClass {
private:
    static int count;
    struct repeating_timer main_loop_timer;
public:
    MyClass();
    friend bool main_loop_timer_callback(struct repeating_timer *t);
};

//////// test.cc
#include <iostream>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "test.h"
using namespace std;
bool main_loop_timer_callback(struct repeating_timer *t) {
    MyClass::count++;
    cout << "callback " << MyClass::count << endl;
    return true;
}

MyClass::MyClass() {
    add_repeating_timer_us(-50000,
                           main_loop_timer_callback,
                           NULL,
                           &main_loop_timer);
    count = 0;
};

/////// test-main.cc
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "test.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    MyClass test;
    stdio_init_all();
}
```

Comment: please show how you are compiling plus the complete error message

Comment: Learn about [*lambdas*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) which can *capture* variables, including `this`. So you could have something like `[this]() { member_function(); std::cout << member_variable << '\n'; }`

Comment: Pass non-NULL `user_data` to `add_repeating_timer_us`, read out `t->user_data`? Based on [Pi Pico docs](https://raspberrypi.github.io/pico-sdk-doxygen/group__repeating__timer.html)

Comment: And if you need to store function with a specific signature, you could use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). It can store *any* callable object with the required signature. For the lambda shown in my previous comment it would be `std::function<void()>`.

Comment: Do you really want to declare `count` as *static* (i.e. to share one variable named `count` amongst all of the instances of `MyClass`?). If so, you'll need to add a `int MyClass::count = 0;` somewhere into your .cpp file; but if not, you should remove the `static` declaration.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik: I don't think that duplicate close is helpful.

Comment: Really, @Hasturkun, that duplicate doesn't include a missing definition of a declared static class member? I'm fairly confident that it does.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I'm guessing it's an X Y, User wanted to access a class member. Instead of passing the class as the callback's context/user data, they made a member static and failed to reference it correctly. The undefined reference is a side effect of that, not the primary point.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik is it helpful as in will someone with the same problem reading the accepted answer of the linked question reach the right answer in finite time?

Comment: My question is not about the error message, but, how do I code the callback?

Comment: Set `user_data` (arg #3 of `add_repeating_timer_us`) to `this` instead of `NULL`. Inside callback take `t->user_data` and cast it to `MyClass *`. Now you have the instance that called the registration and can call methods on it the usual way.

Comment: I've made some minor edits to the question, and will probably post an answer later, assuming this reopens. The answer is basically the same as my comment above suggests, and teapot418's says explicitly, though.

Answer (score 1):

The [Pi Pico `repeating_timer` API](https://raspberrypi.github.io/pico-sdk-doxygen/group__repeating__timer.html) allows you to pass a `user_data` argument when adding a timer (the third parameter to `add_repeating_timer_us`).

This value is later returned in the `user_data` member of the `struct repeating_timer` passed to your callback.

This can be anything you want, e.g. in your case, a pointer to `MyClass`, so long as you cast it to and from `void *`.